# CodeIgniter 4, Error en CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DataException

Tags: php, html5, base-de-datos, codeigniter-4

Tengo 5 años usando CodeIgniter 3, estoy aprendiendo los cambios a CodeIgniter 4, en unas pruebas que realizó al intento de crear el login de usuario así como el registro del mismo, al enviar los datos a guardar en la DB me da este error y no logro saber el porqué del mismo y no hallo la solucion me pueden ayudar el error es este:
**CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DataException
Allowed fields must be specified for model: App\Models\UserModel**
[image: Así muestra el error]

Este es mi controlador

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class UserModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $allowedFileds = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'created_at', 'update_at'];
    protected $beforeInsert = ['beforeInsert'];
    protected $beforeUpdate = ['beforeUpdate'];

    protected function beforeInsert(array $data)
    {
        $data = $this->passwordHash($data);
        return $data;
    }

    protected function beforeUpdate(array $data)
    {
        $data = $this->passwordHash($data);
        return $data;
    }

    protected function passwordHash(array $data)
    {
        if (!isset($data['data']['password'])) {
            $data['data']['password'] = password_hash($data['data']['password']. PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Este es mi modelo

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class UserModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $allowedFileds = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'created_at', 'update_at'];
    protected $beforeInsert = ['beforeInsert'];
    protected $beforeUpdate = ['beforeUpdate'];

    protected function beforeInsert(array $data)
    {
        $data = $this->passwordHash($data);
        return $data;
    }

    protected function beforeUpdate(array $data)
    {
        $data = $this->passwordHash($data);
        return $data;
    }

    protected function passwordHash(array $data)
    {
        if (!isset($data['data']['password'])) {
            $data['data']['password'] = password_hash($data['data']['password']. PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para poner códigos y mensajes de error como texto, con imágenes es muy difícil analizar.

Comment: Ok gracias entiendo ya la modifico

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error gramatical.

**App\Models\UserModel.php**

En lugar de:

```php
// ...
 protected $allowedFileds = // ... ❌
// ...
```

Utilizar esta:

```php
// ...
protected $allowedFields = // ... ✅
// ...
```